# How do I query two different databases in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I have a project in CodeIgniter 4 where I need to join two tables from different databases. I have seen other threads on this but they always assume the full text name of the second database. My databases are configured in the .env file, then instantiated. My code is as follows. What is wrong with my syntax?  I am getting the famous:
"Object of class CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Connection could not be converted to string" error. Here is my code.

...

```
/**
* DashModel constructor.
*/
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db = \Config\Database::connect('default');
    $this->www = \Config\Database::connect('www');
    $this->data = \Config\Database::connect('data');
}

/**
* @return int
*/
public function getUsersCount()
{
    $mydata = array();
    $sql = "SELECT distinct o.patient_id FROM observations o
            JOIN($this->www->table('patients as p'), p.id=o.patient_id)
            WHERE o.observations_devices_id='6'";
    $query = $this->data->query($sql);
    $mydata = $query->getResultArray();
    return $mydata;
```

Comment: You won't be able to use different connections to query two databases. If they are on the same server, you'll need to use the `database.table` syntax. If they aren't on the same server, you won't be able to do a join.

Comment: You can't put a function call inside a string. If the function returns a string, you can assign the call to a variable, then substitute that variable into the string. But I don't think that's what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The are on the same server. I typically include the database in the query line. Maybe there is a different way to do it? I am trying to avoid hard-coding the database names as they are different on my dev and production servers. I want to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There is no way around the text-string naming of the database, but you can put it in a variable.

So I did this:

...

```
/**
 * DashModel constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db = \Config\Database::connect('default');
    $this->www = \Config\Database::connect('www');
    $this->data = \Config\Database::connect('data');
    $this->utillib = new Utillib();

    // set up string for multi-db queries
    $this->wwwdb = "bodiwww";
    $this->datadb = "bodiwww_data";
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getUsersCount($gender=false)
{
    $mydata = array();
    $sql = "SELECT distinct o.patient_id FROM patients p
            INNER JOIN ".$this->datadb.".observations o ON o.patient_id=p.id AND o.observations_devices_id=6
            WHERE p.gender='female'";
    $query = $this->www->query($sql);
    $mydata = $query->getResultArray();
    return count($mydata);
}
```

...

And those database name strings can also be pulled from the database config array, rather than hard-coded.

Comment: [`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.patient_id)`?](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php)  ...and you hardcoded the gender in your SQL.

Comment: Yea. that was just for testing. :) Making sure I could include a where clause. I did replace the hardcoded strings with the .env session vars so it is transportable code now.